# If we centered the matrix then the rank is at most d-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I have found that centering is defined as:
We let $\bar{x}$ be the in-sample mean vector of the input data so $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n$ and in matrix notation can be written as $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}X^T1$, $1$ is the column vector of N 1's. Then we substrate the mean from each point $z_n=x_n-\bar{x}$.

By calculation we have that $Z=X-1\bar{x}^T$ hence we have that:
$$\bar{z}=\frac{1}{N}Z^T1=\frac{1}{N}X^T1-\frac{1}{N}\bar{x}1^T1$$
And use definition of $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}X^T1$ and that $1^T1=N$ and get:
$$=\bar{x}-\frac{1}{N}\bar{x}N=0$$
Thus, the transformed vectors are ‘centered’ in that they have zero mean, as desire. But now I have to use this definition of centering, to show that if we have $dxd$ matrix denoted S, then if we centered the matrix then the rank of the resulting matrix at most $d-1$. I'm a bit confused how to prove that. I'm not sure about centering matrix, but I think if we get that the result matrix is $d$ or higher then we do not have that the  transformed vectors are ‘centered’ and they will not have zero mean? But how can I prove that? Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the rank of a matrix affected by centering the columns of a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721486/how-is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-affected-by-centering-the-columns-of-a-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

$\bf 1$ is a left kernel vector of $S$, as you computed, ${\bf 1}^TS=0$. Thus $Z$ can not have full rank, as you have $S$ given as square matrix.